# Disable data bind in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, data

I am trying to get rid of JS from my store to make it work at best without JS at all because it takes a lot of time to process all JS logic and in my country, we still use 2G networks and as a result, the website is really slow.

I have found a lot of statements like

```
data-bind="text: new String('Welcome, %1!').replace('%1', customer().fullname)"
```

First of all, I don't understand the purpose of such binding, this data won't change.

Is there any way to disable this completely, and use server-side data load?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KnockoutJS` in Magento 2 deals with dynamic display of UI components I do not think this is the best way to optimize.

Magento 2 uses the `Knockout.js` framework to dynamically build some parts of it's frontend. It provides a great way to create interactive frontend data bound components within your Magento 2 store. `Knockout.js` eases working with dynamic javascript user interfaces by making use of the **Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM)** pattern.

Features of Knockout.js

- Observables and dependency tracking
- Declarative bindings
- Templating

But if you still want to do this, this is crazy, you may have a gap with Checkout. It is better to look for optimization work in **custom modules**. *Maximum compression, css, custom javascript in a customizable theme.*

Comment: Thank you for you response, so basically there is no easy way to disable ajax requests and output data directly ?

Comment: @solderingiron This is not ajax it's KnockoutJS. There's no easy way. This is part of Magento 2. This is the same if a person has to replace veins. Sorry for the comparison.

Comment: Thx, there is nothing impossible, could you just edit your answer explaining what is the purpose of using Knockout JS in Magento ? there is no highly dynamic UI that should be synchronized ...

Comment: @solderingiron Yes ,  I could)